# How to vertical align content in bootstrap 3 with unknown height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Yet another vertical align question ....

I'm trying to vertically align the icons to the middle of the div.

[Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/116839)

So far i tried playing around with `display:inline-block`, `display:table-cell` and [this](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) solution by CSS tricks. Problem is - the height is unknown.

I've currently set `padding-top:50%` and it works nice but it's not responsive. Check out the mobile view to see it expanding out of proportion.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is the CSS for the `table`/`table-cell` solution - It's not working as well.

```
.calc-field-control { 
  display : table!important;
}

.calc-field-control-list {
   display:table-cell!important;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to known the `height` to use the `table-cell` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bootstrap columns you need to remove the float like this..

```
.calc-field {
    display:table !important;
}

.calc-field-control {
    display:table-cell !important;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    float:none;
}
```

Updated Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/116888